# Can I get a Cosmos DB operation to fail if a different operation on the resulting change feed update fails?

Tags: transactions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a bunch of sub objects embedded in a parent object. The parent objects are in a collection partitioned by something that makes sense for the parent.

I want to use the change feed to maintain a collection of these sub objects, partitioned by a field which should be globally unique for all such sub objects.

I want to set things up such that when a user tries to modify something in the parent object, and that modification would result in a duplicate entry in the change feed driven sub object collection, the user is prevented from doing so.

Ideally this would manifest as some sort of transaction whereby the modification to the parent object is made, the change feed tries to do it's thing (in the same transaction) and fails and so the parent object modification is rolled back.

Is this kind of work flow possible?

Comment: This is not possible. There are no transaction guarantees between a container and change feed.

Comment: @MarkBrown I think another penny is about to drop for me on this stuff; I suppose the solution is to keep the sub-obejcts and the parent objects (ex sub object) in different collections, for writing. Then use the change feed to denormalise to the full thing. I can manage the uniqueness of the sub objects in the dedicated container.

Comment: Change Feed is very often used to manage denormalized data so that is a better choice to keep sub objects in a separate container and use a unique partition key and id to maintain uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mark and I don't think CosmosDB can meet your requirement. Change feed is more likely a trigger to handle some data in IOT, and it's not designed for actions like transaction. I also googled for some idea but failed.

Did you take adding modify policy to client side rather than database into consideration? I mean maybe you can have another view to edit data.